# How to plot in python for count of repeated text

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot my data-frame using seaborn and matplotlib, but getting error like cannot convert string to float.

My data is like:

```
ID     |  Status     | Date | Columns|
-------+-------------+------+--------+
28     |  ACTIVE     |      |        |  
29     |  ACTIVE     |      |        |
49623  |  TERMINATED |      |        |
49624  |  TERMINATED |      |        |
49625  |  TERMINATED |      |        |
```

For what I have tried so far:

df_count = df.apply(pd.value_counts)
plt.plot(df_count)

where df_count looks like

```
           |STATUS|
-----------+------+
ACTIVE     |38537 |
TERMINATED |1185  |
```

When trying to do `sns.barplot(df)` it gives following error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

And trying to do `plt.plot(df)` it gives following error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '12/31/2014 0:00'

My python plotting seems to be quite zero please suggest.

Comment: It might help if you told us, how the resulting plot should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to specify the x and y. Please try:

sns.barplot(x=df_count.index,y=df_count.Status)

sns.plt.show()

-edit

test.csv:

```
,STATUS
ACTIVE,38537
TERMINATED,1185
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter=',')
df.index.names = ['Type']

sns.barplot(x=df.index,y=df.STATUS)
sns.plt.show()
```

output:
[image]

Comment: please suggest me something to make my plotting skill good. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the integrated plotting functionality of pandas, using 
`df_count.plot(kind="bar")`.

Here is a complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cats = np.random.choice(["Active", "Terminated"], 100, p=[0.43, 0.57])
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": np.arange(100), "Status":cats, "unusedData":np.random.rand(100)})

df_count = df[["Status"]].apply(pd.value_counts) 
df_count.plot(kind="bar")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Last two answers were with `pandas` and `seaborn`, this one is with `matplotlib`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"STATUS": ['Active', 'Terminated'], "counts": [38537,1185]})
x_pos = np.arange(df.shape[0])
plt.bar(x_pos, df.counts, align='center', color=['green', 'blue'], alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(x_pos, df.STATUS)
plt.ylabel('Counts')
plt.title('STATUS')
plt.show()
```

[image]